# Why does python's daemon behave differently on docker and docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, daemon

My test code `test.py` is as follows，

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
import time


class TestDaemon:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        p = Process(target=self.hello)
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    def hello(self):
        while True:
            print("Hello, daemon")
            time.sleep(5)


def test_thread():
    while True:
        print("Hello thread")
        time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Start TestDaemon")
    test = TestDaemon()
    test.start()
    print("Finish starting TestDaemon")
    t = Thread(target=test_thread)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

The `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` are as follows:

DockerFile

```sh
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/client/

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

COPY ./test.py ./

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["test.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    image: test:1.0.0
```

I build a docker image by using the command: `build -t test:1.0.0 .`

Finally, I use docker and docker-compose to run this image and find different behave of my test code.

The log below is from the container started up by `docker run -ti test:1.0.0`

```
Start TestDaemon
Finish starting TestDaemon
Hello thread
Hello, daemon
Hello thread
Hello, daemon
Hello thread
Hello thread
Hello, daemon
```

The log below is from the container started up by `docker-compose up`

```
Recreating naocs_cli_test_1 ... done
Attaching to naocs_cli_test_1
test_1  | Start TestDaemon
```

It is so weird that same code has different behavior in `docker run` and `docker-compose up`.
Does anyone know the reason? Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you try adding `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` to the service? These are different from your `docker run` command.

Comment: @AndyShinn, Thanks very much. It works finally. I add `-ti` in `docker run` but I ignored these two options in `docker-compose.yml`. I thinks I need to learn more details about `docker-compose inference` and `Docker inference`. Thanks.